# XSLT: use xls:sort attributes (dynamic sorting)

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

what How do I apply a parameter to a select and order attribute in a xsl:sort element?

```
<xsl:param name="gubun" select="'AMOUNT'"/>
   <xsl:param name="va" select="'aaa'"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()">
  <xsl:sort select="*[name() = $gubun]/@aaa" order="{$order}" data-type="number"/>    
        </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:copy>
```

what attribute Dynaminc?

```
<xsl:sort select="*[name() = $gubun]/@$va" order="{$order}" data-type="number"/>
```

why error??? @$va ?

Comment: try `*[name() = $gubun]/@*[. = $va]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `<xsl:sort select="*[name() = $gubun]/@*[local-name() = $va]" order="{$order}" data-type="number"/>`.